# @Valid cannot be resolved to a type Spring 4.0.3

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I am facing the issue that @Valid annotation cannot be resolved, though i have added the dependency , configured pom.xml and Default-servlet.xml

Please find the codes below:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String loginProcess(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User userToBeValidated,BindingResult result , HttpServletRequest request){
```

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

**DefaultServlet-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: Are you sure the annotation is required?

Comment: Sorry @RomanC didn't get you. I think i require that annotation to validate a form backing bean. but i am not getting my mistakes

Comment: Can you tell me which package this annotation from?

Comment: i think its from javax.validation.valid

Answer (score -1):

As far as I remember the @Valid annotation is part of the validation-api JAR which you can find in the lib directory of the Hibernate Validator, as you have already downloaded the Hibernate implementation. The @Valid is a part of the javax.validation annotation API. You can add this JAR to your class path to be able to properly reference the annotation.

Comment: OP already has `javax.validation:validation-api` in his `pom.xml`.